# Zipcode API causing SyntaxError

Tags: jquery, api

I'm trying to use this Zipcode Distance and Radius API: https://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com
 But I'm getting an error "**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :** " that prevents the data from being sent to the console log. However, if I click on "sources" in chrome's developer tools I can see the data sitting there (not in the console, but somewhere else):

```
{"zip_codes":[{"zip_code":"19801","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19802","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19803","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19804","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19805","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19806","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19807","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19808","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19809","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19810","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19850","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19880","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19884","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19885","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19886","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19890","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19891","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19892","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19893","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19894","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19895","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19896","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19897","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19898","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19899","distance":0.009},{"zip_code":"19889","distance":0.867}]}
```

Here is my code:

```
var requestURL = 'https://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com/rest/2sd1f31DsfsdfsdPfOezWRkmc2Z14HkhGGuCAycWqP6N7ADmoRWkJgGVi/radius.json/19803/2/mile';

 $.ajax({
    url: requestURL,
    dataType: "jsonp", // will automatically add "?callback=jqueryXXX"
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    type: "get",
    success: function(data) { 
        console.log(data); 
        }
    });
```

I've seen a number of posts on stackoverflow that are similar to this, but none of them seem to fix my problem. Maybe it's specific to this API.

Comment: Have you registered your application to get access to API?

Comment: Yes, I have an API key and I'm registered.

Comment: BTW, I changed my api key in this post so if you try to use that one then it won't work.

Comment: As i see it, server returns JSON, not JSONp. But i really don't know how you should hanlde this API. Maybe contact their own service and ask for help